# IntelliJ: Delete Highlighted Portion With Just the Delete Key

Tags: intellij-idea

One of the more annoying aspects of IntelliJ for me is how the default way to delete a portion of text I highlight with my mouse is to press shift+delete, rather than simply delete. I'm aware that I can go to Preferences --> Keymap to customize controls like this, but I'm not sure exactly which function to change and how to set it to the delete key.

I'm using the 2016.1.3 Community Edition for OS X.

Comment: I have been using Intellij IDEA for a long time now and never encountered this. Currently on 2015 ultimate on OSX. Can you include the version & the OS you are on; in the question?

Comment: @Bajal updated the question

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a solution for you as I cannot reproduce this in 15.0.6. Hopefully someone on 206.13. can help you

Comment: This is certainly not the default behaviour. You should report a bug.

Comment: @jangroth but could I have accidentally turned on some other key mapping that allows the behavior (in which case it isn't a bug but rather a matter of changing back the preferences)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on — I had rather absentmindedly installed the IdeaVIM plugin, which adds weird (vim-like) keybindings, one of which is that you need to press shift+delete to delete a highlighted portion.